# Proof that if $av = 0$ then $a=0$ or $v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

For the proof given in the title I came up with an initial idea, which I could not verify so far. Thus, I would like to know what I am doing wrong:

Suppose $a \in F$, $v \in V$ and $av=0$. Prove that $a=0$ or $v=0$.

1. If $a=0$ then we know from the definition, which is given in the book I am reading (Linear Algebra done right), that $0v=0$, which suffices as a proof that if $av=0$ then $a=0$.
2. If $a \neq 0$, then there exists the inverse multiplicative $a^{-1}a=1$.
   Furthermore, we know that the additive inverse of $v \in V$ is $v + (-v) = 0$. Hence, I tried the following:

\begin{align}
&v + (-v) = 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow 1v + 1(-v) = 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow (a^{-1}a)v + (a^{-1}a)(-v)=0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow a^{-1}(av) + (a^{-1}a)(-1)v=0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow a^{-1}(0) + (-1)(a^{-1}a)v=0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow 0 + (-1)(1)v =0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow (-1)v =0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow v =0 \\
\end{align}

which holds for $a \in F$. So if $a \neq 0$ and $av=0$ then we can conclude that $v=0$. I know this is probably too complicated for that proof, but I wanted to stick to my approach to find out what I am doing wrong to get better at proof writing. Any error corrections or advice are appreciated!

Comment: If $a \neq 0$ then $v=1v=(a^{-1}a)v=a^{-1}(av)=a^{-1} 0=0$.

Comment: What is $V$ and what is $F$? For vector spaces it holds, otherwise not.

Comment: $V$ is a vector space over $F$, and $F$ is the real vector space / complex vector space. The author states that it should be obvious from the context, if we consider the real or complex vector space. For this proof it does not seem to matter. Also, I know that other, easier proofs exists, such as stated from @geetha290krm, but for practicing I wanted to know if mine works aswell

Comment: I don't see much sense in a proof which is too long. If there is a short nice argument, I would practice this one. In essence, it is your proof, but "improved". Also, I would always define the notations (and not only in the comments).